# Bolding a text node in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to bold text in my paragraph, but am not sure what to append exactly. Here is my code.

```
<p id="para">
  Hello World
</p>

var para = document.getElementById('para');
var bold = document.createElement('STRONG');

para.appendChild(bold);
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: This will append `<strong></strong>` into your paragraph tag... it won't wrap the content within that.... Maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h61r3th9/ This will copy the content, construct the strong tag ready for appending, clear the existing content and then replace it with the constructed strong tag.

Comment: Why not just style it with CSS?

Comment: I'm trying to challenge myself to come at a problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strong` element has to contain a *textnode*.

```js
var para = document.getElementById('para'),
    bold = document.createElement('strong'),
    textnode = document.createTextNode("I'm bold!"); 
    bold.appendChild(textnode); 
    
    para.appendChild(bold);
```

```html
<p id="para">
  Hello World
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace text content with `strong` element:

```
// Get paragraph element
var para = document.getElementById('para');

// Create a strong node
var bold = document.createElement('strong');

// Get first child element of paragraph which is a text node
var textNode = para.firstChild;

// Append text to new strong node
bold.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textNode.nodeValue));

// Replace old text node with new strong node
para.replaceChild(bold, textNode);
```

**JS Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q9mpa7ws/3/**

CSS only approach: https://jsfiddle.net/hrecvvbj/1/

Styling with JavaScript approach: https://jsfiddle.net/qynek529/2/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about appending a new node at all; simply alter the font-weight through JavaScript's `fontWeight` [DOM Style Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp):

```js
document.getElementById("para").style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

```html
<p id="para">
  Hello World
</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your concerns as separated as you can. Create a css class and apply it.

```
// in your css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

// in your javascript
para.className = 'bold';
```